# Angular 5 : How to integrate html data (which is a formatted text) in a .docx file?

Tags: html, angular, angular5, docx

I'm still a bit newbie in the code game, and i would like some advices from senpai.

**Context :**

I'm making a angular 5 app which has a form, which is using also [QuillJS](https://quilljs.com/), a rich text editor for only one question (the previous questions are simple input field for strings or numbers). My goal is to allow my users to download the form and the text from QuillJS they completed, on a .docx file (Word). And of course i'm doing this because i want to keep the formatted text from QuillJs, otherwise i would have just get a good ol' string.

**Issue :**

The point is, i'm already building a docx file for the first questions of the form and the only method i found for now to put my **html string** from QuillJs in a Word readable data type, is to use [html-docx-js](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js) library.
This [post](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1996) even explain how. But, BUT, i don't want to use saveAs function (see the post), that create a file and put the content in it. I want to put the content in the docx file i'm already creating.

**So here is my question, how would you, senpai, do it ?**

The thing is that i've got a Blob file (cf post), but i don't know how to put it in my docx file. I tried to see if [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) function could do the job, but well... i don't get how to integrate this special Blob file type (which is : application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document) in the docx file.
Maybe there is another way, i'm open to any suggestions, i don't mind at all to change my way of doing.

Thank you. Save internet, give me a tip.

Comment: Can you explain if you question is about merging multiple rich text forms into single docx file?

Comment: Hi @kvetis ! Well it is not the case. My previous questions in the form are simple strings or number which i implement at special place in my .docx file. There is only one rich text form. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation for html-docx-js does not state any other options than the `asBlob` method. I suggest two options:

### Decoding the DOCX:

The Blob filetype is not special. The blob is just binary representation of the docx. I found in [SE question](https://superuser.com/questions/278260/how-do-i-see-the-xml-of-my-docx-document) that the docs in fact zipped XML document. You could unzip it using JSZip or other JS solution, then read it using `FileReader` and try to deal with it in a DOM manner. I'm not qualified to go into details how that could work.

### Adding HTML to the user input first and then outputting it as a whole

This is changing the way you want to do it. In this way, I would first create formatted HTML with the data you collected in other parts of the questionnaire. Then you append the rich data from the rich editor. At last you take this HTML data and save it into single file using the `asBlob` function.

The second solution will maybe strip some customization from your original approach, but it seems much faster to implement.

Comment: Thank Kvetis for your answer. For now i have to do a pause in my code development for personal reasons, but i will definitely try your solution soon i can and will give some reply to it here.